# PHP string containing two forward slashes in

Tags: php, string

This is probably a very simple question, but I just can't figure it out. I want to define a string containing two forward slashes

```
$htmlcode="text//text";
```

From what I understand what follows after // are comments.

**Question:** How do create a string containing //?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parsing of the language is a little bit tricky. Within a string literal, comments and other language features are not triggered (except for special characters which need to be escaped). Also, within block comments, line-comments are not valued.

```
$example1 = 'hello /* this is not a comment */ '; /* but this is */
$example2 = 'hello // this is not a comment '; //but this is
$example3 = "works the same with double quotes /* not a comment */ //not a comment ";

/* comment example
   $thisIsAComment
   //this does not escape the closing */
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$htmlcode="text//text"; //this is comment.
```

Your string is already defined as you want it to be. 
Check out docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php

You should use some IDE or syntax highlighter, you will understand code more clearly.
Notepad++ is free and lightweight http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download

Comment: Seconding NotePad++.  It's great.  Even supports HEREDOC syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine.

I would highly suggest reading the [Basic Syntax - Comments](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php) guide to get a better understanding.

Comment: My PHP code contains this: $htmlcode1 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> \n <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C"; When I try to echo the string, I get 0. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry Mike, I see my mistake in not putting a backslah infront of the last " Thanks

Comment: No problem, Thomas. Good Luck!